# dynamic adding the row in the table using jquery working in IE8 or below but not in chrome or edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an old IE application, where we are adding the row dynamically in the table

JS function for adding new row

```
function doAddVendor(vendorCode,vendorName){
    var vendorTable = document.getElementById('vendorTable');
    var idx = $('#vendorTable').children('TBODY').children().length-1;
        
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr tag="trVendor" class="TableLeftWhite" id="trVendor'+idx+'">';                     
    html += '<td><input type="text" readOnly="true" tag="txtVendorCode" value="'+vendorCode+'" name="txtVendorCode'+idx+'" id="txtVendorCode'+idx+'" class="FormTextBoxReq" style="width:78%"/><input type="button" id="btn_port" name="btn_port" value=". . ." style="text-align :right;" onclick="openVendorHelp(\'txtVendorCode'+idx+'|txtVendorName'+idx+'\',\'retVendorChoosed\');"  class="FormBtnClrHelp" /> </td>'; 
    html += '<td><span id="txtVendorNameDesc'+idx+'">'+vendorName+'</span><input type="hidden" name="txtVendorName'+idx+'" id="txtVendorName'+idx+'" value="'+vendorName+'"/></td>'; 
    html += '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="chkVendorCode'+idx+'" value="'+idx+'" tag="chkCheckVendorDelete"/></td>'; 
    html += '</tr>'; 
    debugger;   
    
    //Below line works well in IE but on chrome its empty the previous added row
    $('#vendorTable').children('TBODY').html($('#vendorTable').children('TBODY').html()+html);
    

    $('#vendorListSize').val($('#vendorTable').children('TBODY').children().length-1);

}
```

**HTMl CODE**

```
<div style="height: 300px;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%"
                            id="vendorTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15%" class="TableCenterSub">Vendor Code</td>
                                <td width="75%" class="TableCenterSub">Vendor Name</td>
                                <td width="10%" class="TableCenterSub">Select</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

first I add new row as below and fill it with some data
[image]

now when I try to add new row in chrome, its empty the previous row as below image
[image]

When I am adding the row and put any value for first time its added properly but when I tried to add new row,it empty the previous row in chrome while in IE its still populating properly.
One solution I found that I can put the check if the request is coming from IE or chrome based on that I can add the row in different way but this type of code has reutrn multiple time for multiple screens, I am looking for fix in this code so it can work smoothly without changing a lot in the files.
Any help to fix in particular code, will be much appriciate

Comment: Try use this line instead `$('#vendorTable tbody').append(html);`

Comment: It worked for both IE and chrome, Thanks for you help, you can answer the question, will accept it